# How can I prove the equation below

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I want to prove that

$$ ka^2+\frac{1}{k}(b^2) \geq 2ab $$
Assuming that $k>0$.

Is this a variation of $a^2+b^2 \geq2ab$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $k>0$,

$$ ka^2+\frac{1}{k}(b^2) \geq 2ab \iff k^2a^2 + b^2 \geq 2akb.$$

Now let $c=ak$. Then we have

$$
c^2+b^2 \geq 2cb
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=a\sqrt{k}$ and $B=\frac{b}{\sqrt{k}}$.  The original inequality becomes $A^2+B^2\ge 2AB$, which you know how to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is $${x+y\over 2}\geq \sqrt{xy}$$

where $x= ka^2$ and $y=b^2/k$.